# JHipster - how is the user model transferred upon successful login?

Tags: angular, spring-security, jhipster

I'm curious about where in the code the user model gets appended to the response body of a successful login attempt.

In SecurityConfiguration class' configure method, under formLogin, all that i see is the ajaxAuthSuccessHandler, who only sets the http status code to 200.

How is the model transferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by a subsequent GET request to /api/account

Comment: so the client waits for the success response, and then, once authenticated  makes another request to get the user model? couldnt the LoginSuccessHandler just return the model in the first response?

Comment: Yes it could be done this way but it would not work with all authentication types.